# Magento migration 1 to 2 [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trailling to migrate Magento 1 to magento 2, I'm using migrate data tool but this returned a SQL error:

```
[2017-02-13 10:38:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: 

EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:35][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:46][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2017-02-13 10:38:46][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
50% [==============>-------------] Remaining Time: 2 mins


  [PDOException]                                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match the number of tokens
```

This error occurred during customer_address data migrate.

Does someone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error, to solved this only need execute this shell scrit in magento 1:

```
<?php

require 'abstract.php';

class Shell_AddressCleanup extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        /** @var $addresses Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Collection */
        /** @var $address Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
        $addresses = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
        $addresses
            ->addAttributeToFilter('city', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('company', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('country_id', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('fax', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('lastname', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('middlename', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('postcode', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('prefix', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('region', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('region_id', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('street', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('suffix', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('telephone', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('vat_id', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('vat_is_valid', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('vat_request_date', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('vat_request_id', array('null' => true), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('vat_request_success', array('null' => true), 'left')
        ;

        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            try {
                echo $address->getEntityId() . ', ';
                $address->delete();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage(),"\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Shell_AddressCleanup();
$shell->run();
```

I must thank the answerd to dfelton, user in github:
https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/103